# Yii2 Login authentication issue

Tags: yii2

I am having trouble in Authtenticating password for Yii2 in advance fronend. I get following error

"Incorrect username or password."

I know yii2 uses hash authentication. I am providing correct password that I remember from time of signup.

My Password field in database is always blank, there is nothing there, but there are bunch of characters in my password_hash and auth_key.

Is it normal for password field to be blank? or is this a bug in signup process?

Here is my User model code

```
namespace common\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\NotSupportedException;
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;


class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
      public static function tableName()
{
    return '{{%user}}';
}
```

Comment: Better show your user create code!

Comment: Why do you have a password field? Should only need the hash

Comment: Show more code this is not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While storing the password you can use the following function in your User model before saving the details of the user

```
$this->password = Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generatePasswordHash($this->password);
```

Now when the user inputs password you can validate it by using the following code

```
if (Yii::$app->getSecurity()->validatePassword($password, $user->password) == true) {
    /* Password is valid */
} else {
    /* Invalid password */
}
```

Regarding the blank password, it is acceptable by the Yii2 while converting the blank password to hash but is a bad practice for allowing the user to input blank password. You must add the validaiton rule in your  model to avoid blank password input.